# Rust embedded binary size

Tags: rust, embedded

I'm new to Rust and after many fights with the compiler and borrow-checker I am finally nearly finished with my first project. But now I have the problem that the binary gets to big to fit into the flash of the microcontroller.

I'm using an STM32F103C8 with 64K flash on a BluePill.
At first I was able to fit the code on the mc and bit by bit I had to enable optimization and such. Now I compile with:

```
[profile.dev]
codegen-units = 1
debug = 0
lto = true
opt-level = "z"
```

and am able to fit the binary. `opt-level = "s"` does generate a to big binary. The error I am getting then is: `rust-lld: error: section '.rodata' will not fit in region 'FLASH': overflowed by 606 bytes`

As I have under 1000 lines of code and as I would say not so unusual dependencies this seems strange.

There are a few sites like [this](https://github.com/johnthagen/min-sized-rust) with ways to minimize the binary. As these are not for embedded most of the ways to minimize are followed anyway.

How am I able to minimize the binary size and am still able to debug it?

My dependencies are:

```
[dependencies]
cortex-m = "*"
panic-halt = "*"
embedded-hal = "*"

[dependencies.cortex-m-rtfm]
version = "0.4.3"
features = ["timer-queue"]

[dependencies.stm32f1]
version = "*"
features = ["stm32f103", "rt"]

[dependencies.stm32f1xx-hal]
version = "0.4.0"
features = ["stm32f103", "rt"]
```

Maybe there is a problem as I noticed that `cargo build` does compile some sub dependencies multiple times in different versions.

Inside the `memory.x` file:

```
MEMORY
{
  FLASH : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 64K
  RAM : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 20K
}
```

Rustc version `rustc 1.37.0 (eae3437df 2019-08-13)`

*edit*

The rust panic behavior is abort.

The code is view able under: https://github.com/DarkPhoeniz/rc-switcher-rust

Comment: `.rodata` means you have too many/large constants, not necessarily that the code itself is too big. But it seems that both `.rodata` and `.text` share the same segment `FLASH`, so either could be the culprit.

Comment: (Although if 1k LoC of Rust generates 64kib code, then the obvious solution is to not use Rust...)

Comment: I currently create only 5 u8 arrays with a size of 27. Though I do not know which constants are used inside the dependencies...
`arm-none-eabi-size` does result to
`text    data     bss     dec     hex`
`7424     332     112    7868    1ebc`

Comment: My knowledge of Rust is pretty non-existent, but what you should try to do is to get the linker to generate a "map" file. It will contain a list of where all your code and variables go in memory. From there you might be able to figure out if something stands out. Perhaps you have a ton of software floating point libs linked or something like that. STM32F103 is, iirc, a Cortex M3 so it doesn't have a FPU.

Comment: Why do you use a macro to generate 3 different modules of near identical code for accessing 3 different serial ports? That will generate thrice the code.

Comment: Because I am new to Rust and was unable to reproduce the wanted wrapper with generics. Also I counted the macro thrice for my LOC information.

Answer (score 7):

I've run into similar issues and may be able to shed some light on what you can do to reduce the size of the binary you're outputting.

You've already discovered one of them: `opt-level = "z"`. The difference between `s` and `z` is the inlining constraint - essentially, the size of a function where the compiler deems it not worth inlining. `z` specifies this to be 25, `s` 75. Depending on what you are building, this may or may not be a consequent reduction in size (and it affects `.rodata` and `.text` primarily).

Another thing you can play on is the behavior on `panic` on your code. If I remember correctly, the `stm32` target supports both `unwind` and `abort`, with `unwind` enabled on the `dev` profile. As I'm sure you can understand, unwinding the stack is a large and costly process in terms of code size. As such, setting `panic = "abort"` in your cargo file might reduce the binary size a bit further.

Beyond that, it is down to manual tuning, and tools like [`cargo-binutils`](https://github.com/rust-embedded/cargo-binutils) may be extremely useful for this. Depending on your use case, there may be leftover `Debug` implementations which are only sporadically needed, and that is definitely something that you could act on.

Comment: The panic behavior is set to abort.
When I compile without optimization (and set the FLASH bigger so the linker does succeed) `cargo size` does output a size for `.text` of `0x13d2e`. As I only have `0x10000` this is already to big before even any `.debug*` parts start. Though without debug the size of `.text` is only `0x10c3e`.
If I analyse the output of nm and the map file from the linker I do not find function calls I would not expect, though some big calls of the HAL I'm using. Maybe the HAL dependency is way bigger as expected...

Comment: I doubt that. is there a chance you can throw your entire project somewhere so I can have a proper look? it sounds like you're doing something weird but I can't tell from just what you've given

Answer (score 6):

A few other general tips for shrinking the binary:

First, the [cargo-bloat](https://crates.io/crates/cargo-bloat) utility is useful for determining what is taking up space in your binary, then you can make informed decisions about how to modify your code to shrink it down.

Second, I've had significant success by configuring the compiler to [optimize all dependencies](https://rust-embedded.github.io/book/unsorted/speed-vs-size.html#optimizing-dependencies), but leave the top level crate unoptimized for easier debugging. You can do this by adding the following to your Cargo.toml:

```
# Optimize all dependencies
[profile.dev.package."*"]
opt-level = "z"
```

If you want to debug a specific dependency (for example: cortex-m-rt), you can make it unoptimized like so:

```
# Don't optimize the `cortex-m-rt` crate
[profile.dev.package.cortex-m-rt]
opt-level = 0

# Optimize all the other dependencies
[profile.dev.package."*"]
opt-level = "z"
```

Comment: I cloned your repo, by using opt-level="z" on dependencies I was able to get the binary to fit. Running "cargo bloat" showed that you've got hundreds of tiny methods that are 20-100 bytes large, not sure what's generating all of those, but that seems to be the ripe place to focus for shrinking down binary size.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
This was my first project with Rust. After I was unable to solve this problem I left it as is and did non hardware projects with it. So now with more experience I am currently rewriting the hole project.  We will see if run into the same problems again. But nice tips anyway!